# Is there a iOS 5 fallback smart app banner?

Tags: ios5

From iOS 6 forward Safari will show smart app banners when the meta tag below is set on a website (https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=10082012b):

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=311507490"/>
```

I would love to also see this on devices with iOS 5. I have been searching for a while for a jQuery fallback smart banner, nothing found yet.

Is there a iOS 5 fallback smart banner plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. jQuery Smart Banner:

http://jasny.github.com/jquery.smartbanner/#

Comment: Thinking about incorporating this plugin, anyone using it?  Had any issues?

Comment: I use it. And it works perfectly fine. The creator suggested this fix for making it also work in apps like Facebook or Twitter which open a UIWebView. https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner/issues/3

Comment: One downside is you can not pass arguments to your app after it has been installed.  Using smart banners you can use the "app-argument" to pass in arguments after the app runs for the first time.  So if you need this feature I recommend using Apple Smart App Banners if you can (IOS 6 and above) else use something like this jQuery Smart Banner.

Comment: @zingle-dingle: Smart app banners also do not pass app-argument to the app after it has been installed. It only passes app-argument if the app is already installed and you open the app using the banner.